# Почему внедрение dll в запущенный процесс завершает этот процесс с ошибкой?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Я хочу внедрить dll в уже запущенный процесс, чтобы проследить за вызовами WINAPI функций в нём. Для этого из книги Джеффри Рихтера Windows via C/C++ я взял функцию для inject'a dll из 22 главы(22-ImgWalk и 22-InjLib). Протестировал функцию: она работает и вижу, что в приложение загрузилась моя инъектированная dll.
(Я упоминаю это, чтобы показать,что инжектор работает.)

Для перехвата функций я использую библиотеку [detours](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours). Я собрал её через nmake(64 бит), добавил lib-файлы в проект и запустил пробный пример [simple](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/tree/master/samples/simple) через инжектор из книги - всё заработало и вызов sleep перехватился и дополнился "объездной" функцией. (Я это упоминаю,чтобы показать, что библиотека собрана верно.)

Затем хочу запустить пример [traceapi](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/tree/master/samples/traceapi) (он как раз делает то, что мне нужно). [Документация](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/wiki/SampleTraceapi) утверждает,что вывод записывается через второе приложение syelog. Nmake собрал все эти примеры и они работают. Я хочу собрать своими руками dll из [traceapi](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/tree/master/samples/traceapi) и внедрить его через инжектор в нужный процесс и видеть в syelog логи. И тут начинаются проблемы:

<strike>1. Исходник `trcapi.cpp`, где находится DllMain, включает через `#include _win32.cpp` source-файл. Но возникало много ошибок, поэтому содержимое этого _win32.cpp вставил вместо этого include (По определению #include вставляет содержимое файла). Вдобавок оказалось необходимым `#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")`. Верно ли я собрал dll-файл? Может из-за этого возникнет ошибка в дальнейшем?</strike>

2. Собрав dll, я хочу внедрить её в процесс. Инжектор внедряет только что собранную dll в нужный процесс. И целевой процесс падает. Тогда я присоединяюсь к процессу,куда внедрена моя dll, с помощью отладчика VS и вижу ошибку: `Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FFFB53B832D в notepad.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при исполнении по адресу 0x00007FFFB53B832D.Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FFFB53B832D в notepad.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при исполнении по адресу 0x00007FFFB53B832D.` Приложение,пишущее логи, не записало ни одного лога, хоть и функции для отправки сообщения вызывались.
   Проверяю отладчиком Wingbd:

   ```
             trcapi64.dll: DllMain DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH
             trcapi64.dll: DllMain DLL_THREAD_DETACH
             trcapi64.dll: DllMain DLL_THREAD_ATTACH
             trcapi64.dll: DllMain DLL_PROCESS_DETACH
             (794c.9440): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
             First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
             This exception may be expected and handled.
             <Unloaded_dl.dll>+0xd832d:
              00007fff`b231832d ??              ???
              0:007> g
              (794c.9440): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
   ```

В чём может быть причина такого поведения? Почему происходит краш?

Уровень целостности у инжектора высокий(запущен от администратора), а у внедряемого процесса - средний, поэтому в этом ошибки быть не может.

Исходник инжектора(это было оконное приложение, но я сделал его консольным.PID записывается в переменную)

```
    /******************************************************************************
Module:  InjLib.cpp
Notices: Copyright (c) 2008 Jeffrey Richter & Christophe Nasarre
******************************************************************************/


#include "..\CommonFiles\CmnHdr.h"     /* See Appendix A. */
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <malloc.h>        // For alloca
#include <TlHelp32.h>
//#include "Resource.h"
#include <StrSafe.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<tlhelp32.h>


#ifdef UNICODE
#define InjectLib InjectLibW
#define EjectLib  EjectLibW
#else
#define InjectLib InjectLibA
#define EjectLib  EjectLibA
#endif   // !UNICODE



BOOL WINAPI InjectLibW(DWORD dwProcessId, PCWSTR pszLibFile) {

    BOOL bOk = FALSE; // Assume that the function fails
    HANDLE hProcess = NULL, hThread = NULL;
    PWSTR pszLibFileRemote = NULL;

    __try {
        // Get a handle for the target process.
        hProcess = OpenProcess(
            PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |   // Required by Alpha
            PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD |   // For CreateRemoteThread
            PROCESS_VM_OPERATION |   // For VirtualAllocEx/VirtualFreeEx
            PROCESS_VM_WRITE,             // For WriteProcessMemory
            FALSE, dwProcessId);
        if (hProcess == NULL) __leave;

        // Calculate the number of bytes needed for the DLL's pathname
        int cch = 1 + lstrlenW(pszLibFile);
        int cb = cch * sizeof(wchar_t);

        // Allocate space in the remote process for the pathname
        pszLibFileRemote = (PWSTR)
            VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, cb, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
        if (pszLibFileRemote == NULL) __leave;

        // Copy the DLL's pathname to the remote process' address space
        if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pszLibFileRemote,
            (PVOID)pszLibFile, cb, NULL)) __leave;

        // Get the real address of LoadLibraryW in Kernel32.dll
        PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pfnThreadRtn = (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)
            GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("Kernel32")), "LoadLibraryW");
        if (pfnThreadRtn == NULL) __leave;

        // Create a remote thread that calls LoadLibraryW(DLLPathname)
        hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0,
            pfnThreadRtn, pszLibFileRemote, 0, NULL);
        if (hThread == NULL) __leave;

        // Wait for the remote thread to terminate
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

        bOk = TRUE; // Everything executed successfully
    }
    __finally { // Now, we can clean everything up

       // Free the remote memory that contained the DLL's pathname
        if (pszLibFileRemote != NULL)
            VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pszLibFileRemote, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

        if (hThread != NULL)
            CloseHandle(hThread);

        if (hProcess != NULL)
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }

    return(bOk);
}

BOOL WINAPI InjectLibA(DWORD dwProcessId, PCSTR pszLibFile) {

    // Allocate a (stack) buffer for the Unicode version of the pathname
    SIZE_T cchSize = lstrlenA(pszLibFile) + 1;
    PWSTR pszLibFileW = (PWSTR)
        _alloca(cchSize * sizeof(wchar_t));

    // Convert the ANSI pathname to its Unicode equivalent
    StringCchPrintfW(pszLibFileW, cchSize, L"%S", pszLibFile);

    // Call the Unicode version of the function to actually do the work.
    return(InjectLibW(dwProcessId, pszLibFileW));
}


BOOL WINAPI EjectLibW(DWORD dwProcessId, PCWSTR pszLibFile) {

    BOOL bOk = FALSE; // Assume that the function fails
    HANDLE hthSnapshot = NULL;
    HANDLE hProcess = NULL, hThread = NULL;

    __try {
        // Grab a new snapshot of the process
        hthSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwProcessId);
        if (hthSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) __leave;

        // Get the HMODULE of the desired library
        MODULEENTRY32W me = { sizeof(me) };
        BOOL bFound = FALSE;
        BOOL bMoreMods = Module32FirstW(hthSnapshot, &me);
        for (; bMoreMods; bMoreMods = Module32NextW(hthSnapshot, &me)) {
            bFound = (_wcsicmp(me.szModule, pszLibFile) == 0) ||
                (_wcsicmp(me.szExePath, pszLibFile) == 0);
            if (bFound) break;
        }
        if (!bFound) __leave;

        // Get a handle for the target process.
        hProcess = OpenProcess(
            PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
            PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD |
            PROCESS_VM_OPERATION,  // For CreateRemoteThread
            FALSE, dwProcessId);
        if (hProcess == NULL) __leave;

        // Get the real address of FreeLibrary in Kernel32.dll
        PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pfnThreadRtn = (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)
            GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("Kernel32")), "FreeLibrary");
        if (pfnThreadRtn == NULL) __leave;

        // Create a remote thread that calls FreeLibrary()
        hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0,
            pfnThreadRtn, me.modBaseAddr, 0, NULL);
        if (hThread == NULL) __leave;

        // Wait for the remote thread to terminate
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

        bOk = TRUE; // Everything executed successfully
    }
    __finally { // Now we can clean everything up

        if (hthSnapshot != NULL)
            CloseHandle(hthSnapshot);

        if (hThread != NULL)
            CloseHandle(hThread);

        if (hProcess != NULL)
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }

    return(bOk);
}



BOOL WINAPI EjectLibA(DWORD dwProcessId, PCSTR pszLibFile) {

    // Allocate a (stack) buffer for the Unicode version of the pathname
    SIZE_T cchSize = lstrlenA(pszLibFile) + 1;
    PWSTR pszLibFileW = (PWSTR)
        _alloca(cchSize * sizeof(wchar_t));

    // Convert the ANSI pathname to its Unicode equivalent
    StringCchPrintfW(pszLibFileW, cchSize, L"%S", pszLibFile);

    // Call the Unicode version of the function to actually do the work.
    return(EjectLibW(dwProcessId, pszLibFileW));
}


void Dlg_OnCommand() 
{

    // тут PID
    DWORD dwProcessId = 12744;//GetDlgItemInt(hWnd, IDC_PROCESSID, NULL, FALSE);
    if (dwProcessId == 0) {
        // A process ID of 0 causes everything to take place in the 
        // local process; this makes things easier for debugging.
        dwProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId();
    }

    TCHAR szLibFile[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szLibFile, _countof(szLibFile));
    PTSTR pFilename = _tcsrchr(szLibFile, TEXT('\\')) + 1;
    _tcscpy_s(pFilename, _countof(szLibFile) - (pFilename - szLibFile),
        TEXT("dl.dll"));
    if (InjectLib(dwProcessId, szLibFile))
    {
        //chVERIFY(EjectLib(dwProcessId, szLibFile));
        EjectLib(dwProcessId, szLibFile);
        //chMB("DLL Injection/Ejection successful.");
        printf("DLL Injection/Ejection successful.");
    }
    else {
        //chMB("DLL Injection/Ejection failed.");
        printf("DLL Injection/Ejection failed.");
    }

}


int  main()
{
    Dlg_OnCommand();

    return(0);
}
```

И сама dll(она очень большая). (Это файл trcapi.cpp, но вместо include_win32.cpp вставлено содержимое файла win32.cpp)

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Detours Test Program (trcapi.cpp of trcapi.dll)
//
//  Microsoft Research Detours Package
//
//  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
//
#undef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define _WIN32_WINNT        0x400
#define WIN32
#define NT
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#define DBG_TRACE   0
#if _MSC_VER >= 1300
#include <winsock2.h>
//#include<winsock.h>
#endif
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(push)
#if _MSC_VER > 1400
#pragma warning(disable:6102 6103) // /analyze warnings
#endif
#include <strsafe.h>
#pragma warning(pop)
#include"../detour/include/detours.h"
#include "../detour/include/syelog.h"

#if (_MSC_VER < 1299)
#define LONG_PTR    LONG
#define ULONG_PTR   ULONG
#define PLONG_PTR   PLONG
#define PULONG_PTR  PULONG
#define INT_PTR     INT
#define UINT_PTR    UINT
#define PINT_PTR    PINT
#define PUINT_PTR   PUINT
#define DWORD_PTR   DWORD
#define PDWORD_PTR  PDWORD
#endif

#pragma warning(disable:4996)   // We don't care about deprecated APIs.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma warning(disable:4127)   // Many of our asserts are constants.

#define ASSERT_ALWAYS(x)   \
    do {                                                        \
    if (!(x)) {                                                 \
            AssertMessage(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__);              \
            DebugBreak();                                       \
    }                                                           \
    } while (0)

#ifndef NDEBUG
#define ASSERT(x)           ASSERT_ALWAYS(x)
#else
#define ASSERT(x)
#endif

#define UNUSED(c)    (c) = (c)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static HMODULE s_hInst = NULL;
static WCHAR s_wzDllPath[MAX_PATH];
static CHAR s_szDllPath[MAX_PATH];

BOOL ProcessEnumerate();
BOOL InstanceEnumerate(HINSTANCE hInst);

VOID _PrintEnter(const CHAR *psz, ...);
VOID _PrintExit(const CHAR *psz, ...);
VOID _Print(const CHAR *psz, ...);
VOID _VPrint(PCSTR msg, va_list args, PCHAR pszBuf, LONG cbBuf);

VOID AssertMessage(const char* pszMsg, const char* pszFile, ULONG nLine);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Trampolines
//
extern "C" {
    //  Trampolines for SYELOG library.
    //
    extern HANDLE(WINAPI *Real_CreateFileW)(LPCWSTR a0, DWORD a1, DWORD a2,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES a3, DWORD a4, DWORD a5,
        HANDLE a6);
    extern BOOL(WINAPI *Real_WriteFile)(HANDLE hFile,
        LPCVOID lpBuffer,
        DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
        LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
        LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped);
    extern BOOL(WINAPI *Real_FlushFileBuffers)(HANDLE hFile);
    extern BOOL(WINAPI *Real_CloseHandle)(HANDLE hObject);
    extern BOOL(WINAPI *Real_WaitNamedPipeW)(LPCWSTR lpNamedPipeName, DWORD nTimeOut);
    extern BOOL(WINAPI *Real_SetNamedPipeHandleState)(HANDLE hNamedPipe,
        LPDWORD lpMode,
        LPDWORD lpMaxCollectionCount,
        LPDWORD lpCollectDataTimeout);
    extern DWORD(WINAPI *Real_GetCurrentProcessId)(VOID);
    extern VOID(WINAPI *Real_GetSystemTimeAsFileTime)(LPFILETIME lpSystemTimeAsFileTime);

    VOID(WINAPI * Real_InitializeCriticalSection)(LPCRITICAL_SECTION lpSection)
        = InitializeCriticalSection;
    VOID(WINAPI * Real_EnterCriticalSection)(LPCRITICAL_SECTION lpSection)
        = EnterCriticalSection;
    VOID(WINAPI * Real_LeaveCriticalSection)(LPCRITICAL_SECTION lpSection)
        = LeaveCriticalSection;
}




//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Detours Test Program (_win32.cpp of traceapi.dll)
//
//  Microsoft Research Detours Package
//
//  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
//

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Trampolines.
//
int(__stdcall * Real_AbortDoc)(HDC a0)
= AbortDoc;

BOOL(__stdcall * Real_AbortPath)(HDC a0)
= AbortPath;

HKL(__stdcall * Real_ActivateKeyboardLayout)(HKL a0,
    UINT a1)
    = ActivateKeyboardLayout;

ATOM(__stdcall * Real_AddAtomA)(LPCSTR a0)
= AddAtomA;

ATOM(__stdcall * Real_AddAtomW)(LPCWSTR a0)
= AddAtomW;

int(__stdcall * Real_AddFontResourceA)(LPCSTR a0)
= AddFontResourceA;

int(__stdcall * Real_AddFontResourceW)(LPCWSTR a0)
= AddFontResourceW;

BOOL(__stdcall * Real_AdjustWindowRect)(LPRECT a0,
    DWORD a1,
    BOOL a2)
    = AdjustWindowRect;

BOOL(__stdcall * Real_AdjustWindowRectEx)(LPRECT a0,
    DWORD a1,
    BOOL a2,
    DWORD a3)
    = AdjustWindowRectEx;

BOOL(__stdcall * Real_AllocConsole)(void)
= AllocConsole;

BOOL(__stdcall * Real_AngleArc)(HDC a0,
    int a1,
    int a2,
    DWORD a3,
    FLOAT a4,
    FLOAT a5)
    = AngleArc;

BOOL(__stdcall * Real_AnimatePalette)(HPALETTE a0,
    UINT a1,
    UINT a2,
    CONST PALETTEENTRY* a3)
    = AnimatePalette;

здесь и далее будут указатели на функции..
Затем их "объезды"
...
INT __stdcall Mine_WSAInstallServiceClassW(LPWSASERVICECLASSINFOW a0)
{
    _PrintEnter("WSAInstallServiceClassW(%p)\n", a0);

    INT rv = 0;
    __try {
        rv = Real_WSAInstallServiceClassW(a0);
    }
    __finally {
        _PrintExit("WSAInstallServiceClassW() -> %p\n", rv);
    };
    return rv;
}
...
BOOL ThreadAttach(HMODULE hDll)
{
    (void)hDll;

    if (s_nTlsIndent >= 0) {
        TlsSetValue(s_nTlsIndent, (PVOID)0);
    }
    if (s_nTlsThread >= 0) {
        LONG nThread = InterlockedIncrement(&s_nThreadCnt);
        TlsSetValue(s_nTlsThread, (PVOID)(LONG_PTR)nThread);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL ThreadDetach(HMODULE hDll)
{
    (void)hDll;

    if (s_nTlsIndent >= 0) {
        TlsSetValue(s_nTlsIndent, (PVOID)0);
    }
    if (s_nTlsThread >= 0) {
        TlsSetValue(s_nTlsThread, (PVOID)0);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL ProcessAttach(HMODULE hDll)
{
    s_bLog = FALSE;
    s_nTlsIndent = TlsAlloc();
    s_nTlsThread = TlsAlloc();
    ThreadAttach(hDll);

    WCHAR wzExeName[MAX_PATH];

    s_hInst = hDll;
    Real_GetModuleFileNameW(hDll, s_wzDllPath, ARRAYSIZE(s_wzDllPath));
    Real_GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, wzExeName, ARRAYSIZE(wzExeName));
    StringCchPrintfA(s_szDllPath, ARRAYSIZE(s_szDllPath), "%ls", s_wzDllPath);

    SyelogOpen("trcapi" DETOURS_STRINGIFY(DETOURS_BITS), SYELOG_FACILITY_APPLICATION);
    ProcessEnumerate();

    LONG error = AttachDetours();
    if (error != NO_ERROR) {
        Syelog(SYELOG_SEVERITY_FATAL, "### Error attaching detours: %d\n", error);
    }

    s_bLog = TRUE;
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL ProcessDetach(HMODULE hDll)
{
    ThreadDetach(hDll);
    s_bLog = FALSE;

    LONG error = DetachDetours();
    if (error != NO_ERROR) {
        Syelog(SYELOG_SEVERITY_FATAL, "### Error detaching detours: %d\n", error);
    }

    Syelog(SYELOG_SEVERITY_NOTICE, "### Closing.\n");
    SyelogClose(FALSE);

    if (s_nTlsIndent >= 0) {
        TlsFree(s_nTlsIndent);
    }
    if (s_nTlsThread >= 0) {
        TlsFree(s_nTlsThread);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hModule, DWORD dwReason, PVOID lpReserved)
{
    (void)hModule;
    (void)lpReserved;
    BOOL ret;

    if (DetourIsHelperProcess()) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    switch (dwReason) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        DetourRestoreAfterWith();
        OutputDebugStringA("trcapi" DETOURS_STRINGIFY(DETOURS_BITS) ".dll:"
            " DllMain DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH\n");
        return ProcessAttach(hModule);
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        ret = ProcessDetach(hModule);
        OutputDebugStringA("trcapi" DETOURS_STRINGIFY(DETOURS_BITS) ".dll:"
            " DllMain DLL_PROCESS_DETACH\n");
        return ret;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        OutputDebugStringA("trcapi" DETOURS_STRINGIFY(DETOURS_BITS) ".dll:"
            " DllMain DLL_THREAD_ATTACH\n");
        return ThreadAttach(hModule);
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        OutputDebugStringA("trcapi" DETOURS_STRINGIFY(DETOURS_BITS) ".dll:"
            " DllMain DLL_THREAD_DETACH\n");
        return ThreadDetach(hModule);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Я постарался очень подробно описать,что я делал, но я не могу понять,почему происходит ошибка. Можете помочь?

Comment: Чтобы удостовериться в том, что dll собрана правильно, я добавил ординал под номером 1 и запустил с тестовым приложением, которому нужен ординал для запуска процесса через DetoursCreateProcess. В новый процесс, который запустился с помощью DetoursCreateProcess внедрилась dll и перехват произошёл, а значит и dll собрана верно. Поэтому первый пункт из "проблем" решился. Мне по-прежнему нужно внедриться в уже запущенный процесс, поэтому DetoursCreateProcess  не подойдет. Поэтому 2 пункт всё ещё не решен.